# Font not recognized Adobe Acrobat Pro XI

Tags: fonts, adobe-acrobat

I've some problems installing the [Din font](http://fontsov.com/font/dinregular47314.html) in different versions: Regular, Medium and Bold.

All styles are listed under  the same font name on Windows Font utility, but Adobe Acrobat XI Pro recognize only the first style installed.

For example, if I install in this order Regular, Medium and Bold, only Regular font is recognized.

If I install in this order Bold, Regular and Medium, only Bold font is recognized.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Adobe Acrobat.  You should contact Adobe for support.

Comment: Where are you going to use the fonts? For editing text? for specifying form fields? for commenting? If for editing text, I have such issues with Acrobat XI on OSX. Updating to Acrobat DC solved all those issues.

Comment: I'm modifying an existing pdf document that has the Din font embedded on the document itself. 
I'm no editing specific fields but text in general.

Comment: ... I've updated to Acrobat DC with no result ...